# Sending SOAP headers with httprio

Tags: delphi, soap

I have a C# application which I am struggling to emulate in Delphi because the authentication is failing.  I believe this is down to an incorrect authentication header.  The (relevant, working) C# code is like so:

```
public class CustomMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public CustomMessageInspector()
    { }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    { }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        AddHeaderToMessage(ref request, "Authentication", Constants.AUTH_VALUE);
        AddHeaderToMessage(ref request, "Application", Constants.APP_NAME);

        return null;
    }

    private void AddHeaderToMessage(ref Message message, string name, string value)
    {
        var header = new MessageHeader<string>(value);

        var untyped = header.GetUntypedHeader(name, Constants.NAME_SPACE);

        message.Headers.Add(untyped);
    }
}
```

My Delphi equivalent looks like this:

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Soap.InvokeRegistry, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Soap.Rio, Soap.SOAPHTTPClient, SOAPHTTPTrans,
  MembershipService;

type
  TStringHeader = class(TSOAPHeader)
  private
    FVal : string;
  public
    property Value : string read FVal write FVal;
  end;

  AuthHeader = class(TStringHeader);
  AppHeader  = class(TStringHeader);

  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    GetUserButton: TButton;
    HTTPRIO1: THTTPRIO;
    HttpRio: THTTPRIO;
    procedure GetUserButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure HttpRioHTTPWebNode1BeforePost(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer);
  private
    _currUser : User2;
    function svc: IMembershipService;
  public
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.HttpRioHTTPWebNode1BeforePost(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp;  Data: Pointer);
var
  Header : TStringHeader;
begin
  Header := AuthHeader.Create();
  try
    Header.Value := Constants.AUTH_VALUE;
    (svc as ISOAPHeaders).Send(Header);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Header);
  end;

  Header := AppHeader.Create();
  try
    Header.Value := Constants.APP_NAME;
    (svc as ISOAPHeaders).Send(Header);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Header);
  end;
end;

function TForm3.svc : IMembershipService;
begin
  Result := HttpRio as IMembershipService;
end;


initialization
  InvRegistry.RegisterHeaderClass(TypeInfo(IMembershipService), AuthHeader, 'Authentication', Constants.NAME_SPACE);

  InvRegistry.RegisterHeaderClass(TypeInfo(IMembershipService), AppHeader, 'Application', Constants.NAME_SPACE);
```

end.

I believe it may relate to the 'Namespace' value, but am not sure. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Place TXMLDocument on form and Use THttpRio onBeforeExecute and onAfterExecute to save your xml to file and see what's wrong:  XML1.LoadFromStream(SOAPRequest);
 XML1.SaveToFile('Request.xml'); Also - don't you have WSDL for this service ?

Comment: If you had a WSDL for this it would be easier to just import it and let code be generated for you

Comment: I have wsdl, but how does that solve my issue?

Comment: I think what is happening is that header is not mentioned in the contract, but that the code is looking for it.